# Scrape the component names of STOXX EUROPE 600 index from investing.com with R Studio

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web, scrape

I am trying to read automatically the names of  the components of STOXX 600 EUROPE from the website: https://nl.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-components.
See the code below:

```
Library(rvest)
Library(tidyverse)
URL <-  "https://nl.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-components"
publications <-read_html(URL) %>%
#defined the Node
html_nodes("leftColumn") %>% 
html_text() %>% data.frame()
```

But something is going wrong because, I see a dataset with 0 observations. Can somebody help me how I can scrape the names from the STOXX EUROPE 600 index with R studio.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of html_table and the id of the table (`cr1`) you could get a data frame containing the names and the information on prices like so:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
url <-  "https://nl.investing.com/indices/stoxx-600-components"
html <-read_html(url) 

html %>%
  html_node("#cr1") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   ``    Naam     Laatst   Hoog     Laag     `+/-`  `+/- %` Vol.    Tijd    ``   
#>   <lgl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <lgl>
#> 1 NA    3I Group 1.244,00 1.258,00 1.234,50 -11,50 -0,92%  774,92K 17:35:… NA   
#> 2 NA    A2A      1,706    1,722    1,694    -0,007 -0,41%  12,37M  17:35:… NA   
#> 3 NA    AAK      192,8    193,2    191,1    +0,5   +0,23%  246,89K 17:29:… NA   
#> 4 NA    Aalberts 46,93    47,15    46,46    -0,23  -0,49%  66,32K  17:36:… NA   
#> 5 NA    ABB      31,34    31,38    30,98    +0,04  +0,13%  2,71M   17:31:… NA   
#> 6 NA    ABN AMRO 11,29    11,37    11,18    +0,06  +0,52%  2,43M   17:35:… NA
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but how can I get all of the 600 components of the STOXX EUROPE 600? and also how can I get it in a CSV format.

Comment: Probably my finance knowledge is a bit rusty. (; Aren't components the `Naam`? Maybe it's just because I added `head()` to show only the first 6 rows of the result?